# Drivers for a Brother MFC-240C printer, they still exist?

Tags: 10.04, drivers, printing

I'm trying to set up an old MFC-240c printer on an older box with Ubuntu 10.04 for a friend.  I've found a couple of howtos but they all seem to be pretty out of date.  They link to a page on the brother website where a drivers package can be found, but the page doesn't exist anymore.  Brother doesn't seem to be supporting the MFC-240c printer line.

I checked the repositories and found nothing helpful.  Google search has just turned up the old threads and a wiki howto, all pointing to the dead link.
Is there any where else I can find the drivers package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should visit [this](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#MFC-240C) site. Those are the official Brother drivers for the MFC 240C. I have not tried them but I don't see any obvious reason why they wouldn't work.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks, I did a search of the brother website and couldn't find that.

Comment: Those drivers may work, but were way more complex to install than necessary last I checked.

Answer (score 5):

[How about a how to for 10.10](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10056196&postcount=2)? From the link:

Your printer drivers are packaged in [Synaptic Package Manager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/brother-cups-wrapper-bh7).

`sudo apt-get install brother-cups-wrapper-bh7` which will also install the lpr-drivers.

Or search Synaptic Package Manager for mfc-240c and select the drivers it finds and install.

For the scanner you need to download the relevant drivers from the Brother website which for your printer is brscan2 and also follow the instructions that are there including putting

```
# Brother scanners
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

in the file `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules` and install sane-utils

I do not believe this not to work for 10.04 (I found the same instructions for Hardy btw).

Comment: I think we probably will update to 10.10, my friend can't think of a reason not to.

Comment: good call ;) 11.04 with classic is another option if you do not like Unity

Comment: You still need to create your udev rule as Rinzwind points out. I've needed to for every version so far.

Answer (score 0):

You could download the drivers for the MFC 240 C from the brothers website but if you're looking for the PaperPort 12 software that came with the original disk they now want to charge you for it.

It seems like you cannot scan a document and open it with word without it. You need them to make the OCR work which will do that for you. I could not find PaperPort 12 software anywhere for free.

You really need to have that original disk.